# How do I reset .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have copied a previous project that has git allready in it. I have removed .git and .gitignore folders. Then reïnitialized git and generated a .gitignore file. Which is completely empty.

But somehow the files ignored in the previous project still remain ignored in this new project...

so when I run the command

```
git clean -xdn
```

there are files shown...
And my .gitignore file is completely empty. Why is this happening?

How can I reset any .gitignore stuff and start over again with a blank sheet?

Comment: did you try `git rm -r --cache` ?

Comment: it not ignored if you can see it in the output of dry-run command.

Comment: It is correct behavior for `git clean -n` to show files that are not ignored, because those are the ones it will clean.

Answer (score 2):

Your repository is in a correct state.

The output of `git clean -n` is precisely the files that would be removed if you run `git clean`, and such files are those which are both untracked and not ignored.

Since you used the `-x` option as well, you are ignoring any entries in `.gitignore` anyways, so what you see is completely orthogonal to the state of `.gitignore`.

Comment: thank you for the info, I kind of solved my problem by doing a: git add -f thelostfile.php and then I had this previously ignored file back. But I wandered why it remained ignored while the .gitignore file was empty...

Comment: @Julesezaar, How did you ascertain that the file remained ignored?